# How to fix date to minimum and maximum value to a html file

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

this code is not working i want to set min and max value to date is there any possibility to set value only useing html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Date test</title>
</head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <div class="list">
                <div class="row">
                    <label class="item item-input">
                        <input type="date" placeholder="Meeting Date" name="mtgDate" ng-model='lead.meetingDate' ng-readonly="isReadonly" min="02/11/2015" max="01/12/2015">
                    </label>
                </div><br>
                <div class="row">
                    <label ng-show="frm.date.$dirty&&frm.date.$error.min" style="color:red;">below limit</label>
                    <label ng-show="frm.date.$dirty&&frm.date.$error.max" style="color:red;">Above limit</label>
                </div>
            </div >
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

html 5 has a new attribute for input type `date`

you can specific a field for date only like this

```
<input type="date" name="date" min="2015-11-02" max="2015-12-31">
```

Beware that not all browser has implemented this method. If you want cross browser compatibility, it is best to use JavaScript.

Here is a list of browser that supported date type attribute [Browser supported list](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime)

Here is a working example (at least it worked in Chrome) [Date Example](http://jsfiddle.net/4khLmf2q/)

Here is a W3 spec on input type date [W3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.date.html)

Comment: thank u so much  but the alert msg is keep on displaying even if i add dirty

Comment: @YokeshVaradhan html can only deal with the least validation. if you find edge case to be a concern then a javascript validation will bring a better solution. But you should not count on front end validation since users have full control on front end, it is best to do validation in back end, and NEVER trust user input.